# UITableView Cell Dynamic Array not Loading

Tags: objective-c

Please help me figure out why the first line does not print the cell text while the second one does:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [swaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

No error is generated at any time.

Comment: Can you NSLog [swaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] before?  Also you could assign and log the stringWithFormat before assigning to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you want the cell to initialize :

```
NSArray *swaItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
NSString *string = [swaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@", string); 
cell.textLabel.text = string;
```

Works for me.